# Datatables se multiplica en pantalla ( JQuery laravel 8)

Tags: javascript, css, laravel, datatables

Hola buenas tardes a todos, les queria consultar si alguien mas tuvo un problema como este: estoy trabajando con laravel 8, despues de muchos dias peliando para mostrar datos en un datatable lo consegui, pero resulta que me muestra los componentes del datatable por duplicado (el buscador, la paginacion, el select de filtro) como muestro en esta foto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Trabajo con la plantilla AdminLTE, laravel 8...

Asi tengo mi vista en blade:

```
    @extends('adminlte::page')

@section('title', 'Modulo Proveedores')

@section('css')
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
@stop

@section('content_header')
    <h1>Listado de Proveedores Registrados</h1>
@stop

@section('content')
<a href="{{route('proveedor.create')}}" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Registrar Nuevo Proveedor</a>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Exportar Listado de Proveedores</a>
<table class="table table-striper" id="proveedores">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Razón Social</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

  </table>
 @stop

 @section('js')

  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $('#proveedores').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/proveedores/data',
            columns: [
                {data: "id"},
                {data: "razon_social"},
            ]
        });
  </script>
 @stop
```

y en mi controlador tengo esta funcion para enviar todos los registros de la tabla:

```
public function data()
{
   $proveedor = Proveedor::select(['id', 'razon_social']);
   return Datatables::of($proveedor)->make();
}
```

Les agradezco desde ya a todos sus comentarios y ayuda...saludos a todos y que tengan un buen dia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba cambiando el selector a minúsculas `$('#proveedores').dataTable(...)`

Ya que `$().DataTable(...)` devuelve una instancia de API de DataTables, mientras que `$().dataTable(...)` también inicializará un DataTable, pero devuelve un objeto jQuery.

Comment: ¡Expláyate un poco más en tu respuesta! Lee [answer]

Comment: gracias chicos, me sirvio el comentario....